# With jquery can you lock a cursor to a dom element on mousedown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is something I was able to do in AS3, not sure if it's applicable here.  I'm looking to lock the users cursor in the y axis when they mouse down on a scroll bar I'm building that is essentially just a draggable div element using the jquery UI.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to manipulate the mouse using JavaScript, which means what you want cannot be done.

However, you can have `cursor: none`, which by the way is not fully supported by every browser.  Then you can create your own "cursor" and make it so that it only moves vertically during mouse down.  However, after the user mouse up, it won't be in the same position as where your created cursor is.  This is the best you can do.